# Comparing two lists of custom objects

Tags: vb.net

I have two generic lists that I need to compare for any additions or subtractions of entries.
The lists are of a custom class that contains user connection details.

```
Dim ConnectedUsersOld As New List(Of ConnectedUser)
Dim ConnectedUsersNew As New List(Of ConnectedUser)
```

I would like to find:

a) Any ConnectedUsers that are in the ConnectedUsersNew list, that are not in the ConnectedUsersOld list. (New users for this session)

b) Any ConnectedUsers that are in the ConnectedUsersOld list, that are not in the ConnectedUsersNew  list. (Users that have left since the last session)

The ConnectedUsers object has a property called username for comparing.

Comment: The main question is whether the order can change.  A simple where not contained in the other one approach would work (I can easily give you the code if you want) but wouldn't be as efficient as iterating through both of them in order (if you know the order isn't changed for the ones that are in both).  Making stored lists of changes as you add or remove them, however, is by far the most efficient way, although it's okay if that's impossible for you to implement (but you really should)

Comment: I connect to a server, and gather a list of users currently connected. I need to send out messages when a user connects and disconnects. I assumed to best way would be to store all users connected on each check (30 seconds) and then process the differences between the two lists.

Comment: It depends on the number of users you're expecting.  For small numbers of users you can use LINQ:  ConnectedUsersOld.Where(not in connectedusersnew etc.).  A lambda expression would work for that (I use c# so don't know the lambda expression syntax but it should be simple enough).  This is, however, computationally inefficient.  For large numbers of users you should keep two more lists added to when people connect or leave the server storing their names that are deleted once their messages are sent.  hope that makes sense and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim ConnectedUsersOld As New List(Of ConnectedUser)() From { _
            New ConnectedUser() With { _
                Key .Id = 1 _
            }, _
            New ConnectedUser() With { _
                Key .Id = 2 _
            }, _
            New ConnectedUser() With { _
                Key .Id = 3 _
            } _
        }
        Dim ConnectedUsersNew As New List(Of ConnectedUser)() From { _
            New ConnectedUser() With { _
                Key .Id = 3 _
            }, _
            New ConnectedUser() With { _
                Key .Id = 4 _
            }, _
            New ConnectedUser() With { _
                Key .Id = 5 _
            } _
        }

        Dim comparer = New UserComparer()
        Dim newUsers = ConnectedUsersNew.Except(ConnectedUsersOld, comparer).ToList()
        Dim oldUsers = ConnectedUsersOld.Except(ConnectedUsersNew, comparer).ToList()
    End Sub

    Private Class ConnectedUser
        Public Property Id() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_Id
            End Get
            Set
                m_Id = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Id As Integer
    End Class

    Private Class UserComparer
        Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ConnectedUser)

        Public Function Equals(x As ConnectedUser, y As ConnectedUser) As Boolean
            Return x.Id = y.Id
        End Function

        Public Function GetHashCode(obj As ConnectedUser) As Integer
            Return obj.Id
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```